# How can I transfer a date format like 2014/02/13/19:57:00 to an excel readable date format?

Tags: excel

I have tried and change `2014/02/13/19:57:00` to `2014/02/13 19:57:00`, but excel still cannot detect this as readable date format so I cannot change to another date format in excel. I have a whole column of date like this one.

So what can I do in excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ",3)*1
```

This replaces the 3rd occurrence of `/` and replaces it with a space. The `*1` then tells excel to convert it into a number (if possible). Formatting the result as date time should give you the datetime you are looking for.

If for some reason that doesn't work, this formula can be used instead:

```
=(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+RIGHT(A1,8))*1
```

That one takes bits of the date and sticks the time. Again, format the cell as datetime.